# How to change text in editor of wordpress cms

Tags: wordpress

I want to edit the text before publication but with one condition: 
the text in my editor also be edited.

A simple example:

```
function edit_content($the_content){
   return  $the_content.'ali';
}
```

The problem with this code: it properly read the edited text but it does not change the text in the editor.

How can I edit the text in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Filter Hook [`content_save_pre`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre)**

If you want to change the content just before it saved to database, you can use this filter hook:

```
function my_filter_function_name( $content ) {
    // do something with $content

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'my_filter_function_name', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: tank you very much ;)